# How to set a different disk when using vagrant up?

Tags: windows, vagrant

I am using Vagrant on Windows 7.

After I run `vagrant up`,I showed me:

```
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the clone medium 'L:\VirtualBox VMs\ubun
tu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64\box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: could not create new grain directory in 'L:\Virtual
Box VMs\ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL).
VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: error writing descriptor in 'L:\VirtualBox VMs\ubun
tu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64\box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component A
ppliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct Handle
rArg *)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Maybe the reason is that my L disk is full.So how can I set a different disk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly looks like some drive issue, maybe disk space, maybe user permissions.

In your case the error comes from VBoxManage, so the error happens when Vagrant is importing its box into VirtualBox.

In order to change the location of VirtualBox's VMs you need to set it in VirtualBox properties ('Default Machine Folder').

For more info [check the docs](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch10.html#idp50943072)

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the reason. I have change to another disk and everything is OK:)

Answer (score 0):

You need set VAGRANT_HOME. The property "machinefolder" in VirtualBox has to be set through "VBoxManage setproperty machinefolder "